# Where should I place a static library so I can link it with a Rust program?

Tags: rust

I do not know how to link a C library to Rust. Here's what I have done:

My **lib.rs** file contains

```
#[link(name = "test")]
extern {
```

The library is built and has the name `libtest.a`.

I do not know where to put it. I have tried several places, but I still have errors of this type when doing `cargo run`

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
//..
note: /usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -ltest
note: /usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -ltest
note: /usr/bin/ld:.......
//..
```

Translation of the above `/usr/bin/ld: no se puede encontrar -ltest` -> `usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest`

I do not know where to put **libtest.a** so that `/usr/bin/ld` can find it. Cargo does not tell me where the library should be in the project.

My **Cargo.toml** contains

```
[dependencies.test]
path = "./src/test"

[dependencies]
bitflags = "0.7"
libc = "0.2"

[build-dependencies]
make-cmd = "0.1"
```

After reading [the FFI section of the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html) again, I thought that maybe the error messages from before were because I was looking for a shared library, so I made the following changes:

```
#[link(name = "test", kind = "static")]
```

After these changes, I still do not know how to indicate where the library is, but the message now tells me this:

```
error: could not find native static library `test`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Where should I place a static library

Wherever you want. You have to *tell* the compiler where to find it.

---

First, let's create a static library

```
$ cat hello.c
int square(int value) {
  return value * value;
}
$ gcc -c -o hello.o hello.c
$ ar rcs libhello.a hello.o
```

Next, we use a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) to set the value of `rustc-link-search` to point to the directory where I put the library:

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/Projects/stack-overflow/using-c-static/");
}
```

We can now use the functions from the library:

```
#[link(name = "hello")]
extern "C" {
    fn square(val: i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    let r = unsafe { square(3) };
    println!("3 squared is {}", r);
}
```

---

That's the basic functionality. You could also use the build script to specify which library to link, instead of having it in your code (`rustc-link-lib`). I prefer this because then the two configurations are right next to each other.

You should also probably follow the [`*-sys` naming convention](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#a-sys-packages) and create a crate dedicated to exposing the underlying API. Importantly, this crate should specify the [`link` manifest key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#the-links-manifest-key) to avoid duplicate symbols at linking time.

If your build script needs more information, cargo passes many parameters via [environment variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-reads).

If you are compiling C code as part of your crate, you should look into crates like [cc](https://crates.io/crates/cc) or [cmake](https://crates.io/crates/cmake), which make the act of building a piece of software much easier.

Comment: I found two solutions, now I am going to read your response thanks for your time

Comment: I see that in your answer there are some links, which I visit to find the solution I publish, I learned a lot but maybe it took me a long time to find it, bad luck not to have seen your answer before.  Out of curiosity from the **build.rs** you can create the libraries thing I did not know, simple example `gcc::Config::new().file("src/hello.c").include("src").compile("libhello.a");` thanks again.

Comment: I was using `#[link(name = "test", kind = "static")]` But after reading your question i use`#[link(name = "test")]` And I see that it works too, I thought it was mandatory for static put`kind = "static"`

Answer (score 9):

I just found a solution (two) but I do not know if it's the best way:

**1-** way

build.rs file

```
extern crate gcc;

fn main() {

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/home/path/to/rust/proyect/folder/contain/file.a");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=test");
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
//..
build = "build.rs"
//..
```

---

**2-** way

Cargo.toml

```
//..
rustc-link-search = ["./src/lib"]
rustc-link-lib = ["test"]
root = "/home/path/to/rust/proyect/"
//..
```

`["./src/lib"]` -> place to lib.a refence to root

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot place `rustc-link-search` (and related keys) in a *Cargo.toml* file. Are you confusing this with a [configuration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) file (commonly placed in *.cargo/config.toml*)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify the path to the library, and you are on Linux, you can just place it in "usr/local/lib" and say its name in main.rs like this :

```rust
#[link(name = "theLibraryname", kind = "")]
```

Also, you can place any header files in the include folder.

**Note: The library name is without the `lib` prefix and `.a` extension.**