# How to link a C library without calling one of its functions?

Tags: rust, linker, ffi

I'd like to link with `-lm`. Right now, I'm doing it this way:

```
let _link_lm = f64::sin(3.0);
```

I tried putting this in `.cargo/config`:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-args=-lm"]
```

This doesn't dynamically link the library.
Also, using `cargo:rustc-link-lib=m` in a build script is the same as calling `cargo rustc -- -lm` which does not work either.
I check that the library is not linked with `ldd`.

It matters to link the library because this is for a JIT compiler which can call these functions by fetching them using `dlsym`.

How I can link to this library without calling one of its functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I place a static library so I can link it with a Rust program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826572/where-should-i-place-a-static-library-so-i-can-link-it-with-a-rust-program)

Comment: @Stargateur: No, using `cargo:rustc-link-lib=m` in a build script is the same as calling `cargo rustc -- -lm` which does not work either.

Comment: *fetching them using `dlsym`* — doesn't that mean you need to dynamically open the library at runtime as well? See [Does Rust have a dlopen equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22461457/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster: No, `dlsym` looks into the executable as well as the dynamically linked libraries as well.

Comment: I'd say same as in C: don't use the `-l` flag, but instead pass the library directly: `link-args=/path/to/libm.so`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `rustc` call the linker with `-Wl,--as-needed`, so the solution for me was to disable this option:

```
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-Wl,--no-as-needed", "-C", "link-arg=-lm"]
```